# apollo-link-state using nested objects as default

Tags: apollo-link-state

I tried to use below object as default in apollo-link-state

```
 apolloClientDemo: {
  __typename: 'ApolloClientDemo',      
    currentPageName: 'Apollo Demo Default...',
    pages: ["page1", "page2"],
    pageObj:{
        color:"red",
        width:"100"
    }      
}
```

Then I tried to obtain **pages** array and **pageObj** inside **ApolloClient** **Query** component. While I could obtain **pages** array, couldn't obtain **pageObj**.

My query is like below;

```
 query {
     apolloClientDemo @client {
         currentPageName
         pages
         pageObj 
     }   
 }
```

Is there a way to use such nested objects as defaults in apollo-link-state?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the fields of "pageObj" you want to fetch in your query. More like this:

```
query {
     apolloClientDemo @client {
         currentPageName
         pages
         pageObj {
              color
              width
         }
     }   
 }
```

Hope this gives you an idea :)